# How to make a counting animation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation

Ok, so I have to display a text field so that the user can enter an integer. Then display two buttons “Start Animation” and “Stop Animation”.

When the button “Start Animation” is clicked, the web page displays an animated times table in the following manner.

For example, if the user entered the number 6, then the animation displays

6 x 1 = 6, one second later it replaces it with 6 x 2 = 12, one second later it replaces it with 6 x 3 = 18, etc. If it is 6 x 9 = 54, then one second later it becomes 6 x 1 = 6, and then 6 x 2 = 12, and so on.

When the button “Stop Animation” is clicked, then the web page stops the animation. Whatever the equation is currently displayed will stay there on the page.

Here is the code I have so far.

```js
var counter = 0;
var counterSchedule;

function startCounterAnimation() {
  // start the counter animation
  counterSchedule = setInterval(showCounter, 1000);
}

function showCounter() {
  // increase the counter by 1
  counter = counter + 1;
  // show the counter
  var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counter");
  counterSpan.innerHTML = counter;
}

function stopCounterAnimation() {
  clearInterval(counterSchedule);
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="text">
<button onclick="startCounterAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
<button onclick="stopCounterAnimation()">Stop Animation</button>
<br/><br/>
<span id="counter"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand exactly what you wanted help with but I fixed it according to what i understood

```js
var counter = 0;
var counterSchedule;
var input = document.getElementById("number");
var counterSpan = document.getElementById("counter");

function startCounterAnimation() {
  counterSchedule = setInterval(showCounter, 1000);
}

function showCounter() {
  if (~~input.value) {
      if (counter >= 10)
        counter = 0;
      counter++;
      counterSpan.innerHTML = input.value + " X " + counter + " = " + eval(input.value + " * " + counter);
    }
  }

  function stopCounterAnimation() {
    clearInterval(counterSchedule);
    input.value = "";
    counter = 0;
  }
```

```html
<input onClick="stopCounterAnimation()" id="number" type="text">
<button onclick="startCounterAnimation()">Start Animation</button>
<button onclick="stopCounterAnimation()">Stop Animation</button>
<br/><br/>
<span id="counter"></span>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think OP wants it to only go to 10. Also eval = evil, especially since you're dealing with user input here you can execute arbitrary code. Try getting an alert box using the snippet ;)

Comment: @bdbdbd Yeah good input, eval is maybe not the optimal approach but i think its fine in this situation. Also added a numeric check, forgot about that

Comment: Why the hacky codegolfy ~~? Does it matter if it's negative or not integer? It will multiply just fine. I would just check `if (!(isNaN(input.value))` instead

Comment: op said "Whatever the equation is currently displayed will stay there on the page." so you might want to remove the last line where you set it to empty string

Comment: @bdbdbd `~~` is  basically the same thing as `!(isNaN(input.value)` in this case, dont see any reason not use short code in this example. And negative numbers works to

Comment: @Patte thanks very much, thats exactly what I was trying to get at!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question (I don't really see a question) correctly. Your code looks fine but you want it to start over again once it reaches 10?
Try using the modulo operator %
So replace

`counterSpan.innerHTML = counter;`

With

`counterSpan.innerHTML = counter % 10;`

Tell me if I misunderstood the question or not.